# How do I... Quadtrees!

Tags: php, html, quadtree

How can I go about creating a quadtree in PHP, is it even possible?

I would like a "grid like" layout.

So each "node" has 4 "exits" - north, south, east and west.

---

Does anyone have some sample PHP code of a Quadtree because I couldn't find any documentation specifically for PHP :(

I'll be your best friend... (possibly some Rep in there too).

Comment: Give us a clue, what do you mean? You can have an array with each item having four children?

Comment: Sorry, i was losing my mind - question updated

Comment: Of course it is possible

Comment: Sure it's possible. I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't be. Can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then the following might be what you are looking for:

```
$map = array(
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4))
);

$map[0][3][3] = "END OF ARRAY 1";
$map[1][3][3] = "END OF ARRAY 2";
```

etc.

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted solution - it's just a 3D array.. not really what OP is meaning to ask

Comment: This would indeed deserve a class, which could implement ArrayAccess Traversable, Countable interfaces

Comment: @jeriko - as the OP, I know what I meant to ask ;)

Answer (score 3):

The same way you do in any other language.  PHP has references, variables, and even some OO capabilities.  There is nothing missing to make a quadtree implementation even difficult, much less impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at doubly linked lists, which would give you either a row **or** a column in your grid (but not both), then look at extending that to reflect the second dimension.